# Is there a way to define "alternate" string terminators (in addition to the null terminator, \0)

Tags: c++, c, string, performance, null-terminated

I don't necessarily want to do this, but I'm curious. In C/C++ is there a way to define string terminators *other* than the null terminator? For example, is it possible to write this,

```
char* str = "123456|ABCDEF";

char* foo = str;
char* bar = strstr(str, "|") + 1;

// do something here to define '|' as a terminator

std::cout << foo << std::endl;
std::cout << bar << std::endl;

// undo pipe-as-terminator definition
```

and get the output,

```
123456
ABCDEF
```

?

If not possible, then is there *any* way to get pointers to parts of a buffer, *without* allocating/copying memory, and *without* modifying the buffer, *i.e.* overwriting the `|`s to `\0`s?

Comment: Nope.  Though it might be nice in some cases, the concept of zero/null/nil/whatever is too deeply imbedded in logic everywhere to change.

Comment: Wouldn't `std::cout << bar << std::endl;` be UB because it's not terminated?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: lol... not really if you read the title: *in addition to the null terminator*.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas no, I didn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could write a string reference wrapper holding a pointer to a substring and a size, and then use `write` rather than `operator<<`:

```
// Sketch
struct StringRef {
    const char* start;
    std::size_t length;
    // add code to initialize the object out of the substring
};
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const StringRef& s) {
   return o.write(s.start,s.length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you could, since this rule is hard-built inside the compiler. The fact is that the compiler includes the null-trminator at the end of each string constant you declare, by using assembly '.asciz' directive. So unless you modify the source code of gcc, I don't think you can. I don't really know for other compilers such as MSVC. For Clang, I don't know if there is a way to do so or not, and it would need investigation. As an alternative, you could just do it the hard way and type each of your string litterals as
    const char message[] = { 'H','e','l','l','o',' ','!','|' };

But I would like to point out that if compilers impose this kind of restriction, it's for a good reason. For example, imagine a program where you take input text from the user. What if the user enters '|' in his text ? The reason why the null-character was chosen is that it is not possible for users to input this character (since it is not part of the set of printable characters, and I don't know about any keyboard including a 'null' key anyways. At least, you should take another character as the null-terminator, but don't take a character that can easily be entered.

Otherwise, I am interested in Operating System Development, where people like to reinvent the wheel, and I have already seen people who tried to use another technique : prfixing each string with its length, allowing to embed null characters inside the string, as well as providing constant-time strlen() operations. Also, C#/.NET strings are length-prefixed AND null-terminated, though I don't really see the interest of it...

Before I get in more precision, I'd like to know which compiler you are using, and your 'level' in programming (just not to tell you about things you won't understand) x)

Cheers, Abstract

Comment: Historically, it wasn't uncommon for terminals to have a `@` key; on such terminals, control-@ will generally send a NUL byte.  Although NUL bytes are ignored by many kinds of line-buffering logic, not all equipment ignores them.  If a paper-tape punch is enabled, for example, a NUL byte will cause it to advance the paper by one row without punching any holes (incidentally, DEL was represented by a row with all holes punched, and would generally also be ignored).  If one made a mistake punching a tape, the solution was to back up the tape one row and then type a DEL character over it.